# function caller name in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Im guessing there is no way to get the function caller name in an anonymous function, is there ?

```
(function()
{
    var cls = function()
    {
        this.foo = function()
        {
            console.log(arguments.callee.caller); // null
            foo1();
        }

        var foo1 = function()
        {
            console.log(arguments.callee.caller); // foo
            foo2();
        }

        var foo2 = function()
        {
            console.log(arguments.callee.caller); // foo1
            cls.foo(); // local
        }

        var cls =
        {
            foo : function()
            {
                console.log(arguments.callee.caller); // cls.foo2
            }
        }
    }
    return (window.cls = cls);
})();

var c1 = new cls();
c1.foo();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct - they're anonymous. If you need to know their names by callee, you'll need to give them a name. Will something like `this.foo = function foo()` rather than `this.foo = function()` work for you?

Comment: I'm tying to figure out a function stack trace in jQuery.

Comment: Named function expressions, which is what you're suggesting, have serious issues in IE. See kangax's article: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Comment: how can this be done where it is not possible to rename the anonymous function ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in recent versions of Chrome and Firefox as follows. I only recommend this for debugging purposes (e.g. javascript tracing in non-production)

```
var mystery = function() {
   var myNameInChrome = /.*Object\.(.*)\s\(/.exec(new Error().stack)[1];
   var myNameInFF = new Error().stack.split("@")[0];
}
```

Comment: I think in case of myNameInChrome it should be index 1 to get function name. Index 0 gives fully matched regex line.

Comment: This gives me the name of the namespace that my function belongs to and not the caller. Good answer though.

Comment: Rutwick I updated the code example. Did you try it within the anonymous function as shown?

Comment: My chrome browser output this for it's Error().stack (JSONified): `"Error\n    at mystery (<anonymous>:4:27)\n    at <anonymous>:1:1"`

Comment: This works much better in Chrome: [Detailed Stack Trace](https://jsbin.com/rapoxo/edit?js,output)